# xmlhttp readystatechange is null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the below javascript code, i am getting null when I mouse over xmlhttp.onreadystatechange in firebug debug mode. I have written many such codes earlier but I don't understand why is it giving null.  Function written on xmlhttp.readystatechange is never called.  Any help?

```
    var query= {"input": {"ip-list" : [{"ip-address": "23.23.23.23"}]}};
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "/servlet/dashboard/Manage?action=getInfo";
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", getAuthString());
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            if (xmlhttp.responseText){
                console.log('test');  
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(query));
    }
```

Comment: Are you by any chance redefining xmlhttp anywhere else in the script?  You could do a quick search just to make sure.

Comment: I have found the issue, updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out my mistake, spent more than an hour. I had written xmlhttp.send inside the readystatechange.  So it will be never called.

**Corrected code:**

```
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            if (xmlhttp.responseText){
                console.log('test');  
            }
        }   
    };
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(query));
```

Comment: Man that's frustrating.  Glad you found the answer though :)